# Code not working on hacker rank! Works on Repl and Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a test on Hackerrank. My Code never seems to function, not even one test case passes.

I have tried using Jupyter  and reply it works perfectly on them

```
def findNumber(arr, k):
    ls = []
    for x in arr:
        if k == x:
            ls.append(x)
        elif k != x:
            continue
    if len(ls) > 0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

```
  File "solution.py", line 42, in <module>
    fptr.write(res + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

It says stdouput:
no response on stdout

I haven't even written anything after line 20. It's their own built-in function. That I can not delete.

```
f __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    arr_count = int(input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in range(arr_count):
        arr_item = int(input().strip())
        arr.append(arr_item)

    k = int(input().strip())

    res = findNumber(arr, k)

    fptr.write(res + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: I think you should be doing `return "YES"` instead of printing it, as it is expecting a return value to print. Please check the instructions for the question you are answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at how their code is running your function:

```
res = findNumber(arr, k)

fptr.write(res + '\n')

fptr.close()
```

It is expecting a returned string value from the function `findNumber` to add to `\n`, however by default functions return `None` and you are not specifying any return value. Therefor it is trying to do `None + '\n'` inside the `fptr.write()` and erroring out.

So as [Ken Y-N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270789/ken-y-n) suggested, you should return strings instead of printing them yourself.

```
if len(ls) > 0:
    return "YES"
else:
    return "NO"
```